# Merge managed program into unmanaged C++ Executable

Tags: c#, c++, windows, native

My goal is to only have a single executable file.

- **Is it possible to merge a managed .exe into an unmanaged .exe?**

There is a lot of information about doing things the other way around (merging unmanaged code into a managed project) but I haven't been able to find anything about going the other direction.

*Background:*

It's for a system requirements / compatibility checker.
I've written the bulk of it using C# in .NET 2.
However, this part will only run if it's determined that the system at least has .NET 2 installed.
That's where ["DotNetVersionIdentifier.exe"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/06/16/9763379.aspx) comes into play.
It's [unmanaged code](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/914135) will run regardless of if the .NET Framework is installed. Instead of showing a dialog box of installed .NET versions, I've modified the code to run my C# program if .NET 2.0 or greater is installed, or else report a custom message.

- I'd like to pack the C# program inside the C++ executable so that I only need to distribute a single .exe

I've tried using ILMerge, but since my unmanaged code doesn't compile to Intermediate Language, it crashes...

[image: ILMerge doesn't accept unmanaged code...]

I can add my C# project to the C++ solution, but it still compiles to two separate executables.

This approach: [How to Append Data to the End of an .EXE File](http://support2.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B84062&x=12&y=13) sounds like a fascinating, yet outdated hack.

This idea seems like it might work: [How to embed an exe inside another exe as a resource and then launch it](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2009/10/16/how-to-embed-an-exe-inside-another-exe-as-a.aspx) and I'm looking into it now.

Comment: So what type of help are you looking for on SO? Indeed you can add file as resource to either managed or native app, save it and run as links you have suggest.

Comment: I haven't got it working yet, so I'm just putting my feelers out to see if there might be another / better way.

Comment: Still not clear to me... Resources is straightforward way of doing what you ask in title (if it is good for your case - your call)... Linked article looks reasonable... "Should I manually detect if .Net 2.0 installed" would be off-topic as opinion based.

Comment: Okay, I am still working on it. It didn't seem very straightforward when I set out on this adventure. The question isn't asking for opinions. I have a clear problem and I'm seeking solutions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov As it turns out, using Resources did work. The pseudo-code on Kumar's blog needed a bunch of tweaking to get it to work. Also he described adding the file as a resource manually which led to problems in VS for me. I've posted my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to accomplish my goal by using Resources, [as outlined here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2009/10/16/how-to-embed-an-exe-inside-another-exe-as-a.aspx).

Here's how I made it work. (I'm new to C++, so let me know if you see any stupidity)

- Compile the managed code as a single file
- Rename the managed code executable as .txt
- Create a new Visual C++ Win32 Console Application
- Add new item - Resource File (.rc)
- Open the resource file, Add Resource, choose *Import*, enter "TEXT" as the type
- Modify *"DWORD size"* to match the size of the managed .txt file

The rest can be explained with a code dump.
Hopefully this will help someone (C++ newbies like myself...)

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

namespace std
{
    HRSRC hrsrc = NULL;
    HGLOBAL hGlbl = NULL;
    BYTE *pExeResource = NULL;
    HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD size = 8192; //hardcoding the size of the exe resource (in bytes)
    HINSTANCE g_Handle = NULL;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = NULL; // Passing NULL uses the instance that started the process( CSMerged.exe ).

    template <typename T>
    string NumberToString(T pNumber)
    {
        ostringstream oOStrStream;
        oOStrStream << pNumber;
        return oOStrStream.str();
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    hrsrc = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TEXT1), _T("TEXT"));
    if (hrsrc == NULL)
    {
        cout << "hrsc is null! \n";
        cin.get(); // leave the console open.
        return FALSE;
    }

    hGlbl = LoadResource(hInstance, hrsrc);
    if (hGlbl == NULL)
    {
        cout << "hGlbl is null! \n";
        cin.get(); // leave the console open.
        return FALSE;
    }

    pExeResource = (BYTE*)LockResource(hGlbl);
    if (pExeResource == NULL)
    {
        cout << "pExeResource is null! \n";
        cin.get(); // leave the console open.
        return FALSE;
    }

    hFile = CreateFile(L"ManagedCode.exe", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
        WriteFile(hFile, pExeResource, size, &bytesWritten, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    int ret = CreateProcess(L"ManagedCode.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if (ret == 1) { return 0; } // the process started successfully, so I'm done here.
    else
    {
        cout << "CreatePrecess returns " + NumberToString(ret) + ". \n";
        cin.get(); // leave the console open
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Resource.h**
 - This was auto generated, along with the modifications to Recource.rc when I imported the resource using VS2013's GUI.

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define IDR_TEXT1                       101

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

I should a add a couple of other things I had to change to make this run on Windows XP:

- Ensure that the Platform target is Win32
- Set *Configuration Properties>General>Platform Toolset* to **"Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (x120_xp)"**
- Set *Configuration Properties>C/C++>Code Generation>Runtime Library* to **"Multi-threaded (/MT)**